# Cordova CLI 4.0: how to install master / nightly version of cordova-ios?

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen, command-line-interface, iphone-6

With Cordova-CLI 4.0 (http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/10/16/cordova-4.html) you currently install cordova-ios 3.6.3 when doing `cordova platform add ios`

However this version doesn't support the iPhone 6 / 6+ splashcreens and icons - this has been fixed in a later commit as far as I can see (https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/commit/5e136a09a1feae3b12309ee5b33854c18c853f86), and is therefore available in the master  (or "nightly") version of cordova-ios on github.

As such, do you know if it's possible to install the master version of cordova-ios from the CLI?

Many thanks

Comment: have you tried `cordova platform add ios@3.6.4`

Comment: Yes, and as 3.6.4 hasn't been released I get `Unable to fetch platform ios@3.6.4: Error: version not found: 3.6.4 : cordova-ios/3.6.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use master from github until it's released:

```
cordova platform add ios@master --usegit
```

Comment: `usegit` has been removed in cordova@6: https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/01/28/tools-release.html You should now use `cordova platform add git_url#branch` instead.

Answer (score 1):

from `cordova help platform` I found that this works:

`cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios.git`

optionally add `#master` to the command above per the docs for another (non-default) branch, so I can now use 4.2.0-dev